# Zip specific files with AntBuilder

Tags: groovy, antbuilder

I need to zip a collection of files from different location into one zip, keeping their initial relations. For example, I need only a1 and b2 from the following folder structure

```
Top -- A -- a1
         -- a2
    -- B -- b1
            b2
```

and i want the zip file to look like:

```
Top -- A -- a1
    -- B -- b2
```

How can I do that using AntBuilder? 
I've tried:

> def deploymentFiles = [
>           "$HOME/Songs/a.tsv",
>           "$HOME/Songs/b.tsv", ]
>
> def ant = new AntBuilder()
>
> def zipFile = new File("deployment_zipFile.zip")
>
> ant.zip( destFile: "${zipFile.getAbsolutePath()}" ) {
>       fileset( dir: "$HOME" ) {
>           deploymentFiles.each {f ->
>               includes: deploymentFiles.join(",")
>           }
>       } }

but this just zipped the entire HOME folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a directory structure like this:

```
-- home
   |-- Songs
   |   |-- A
       |   |-- a1.tsv
       |   \-- a2.tsv
       |-- B
           |-- b1.tsv
           \-- b2.tsv
```

Then, this code:

```
def HOME = 'home'
def deploymentFiles = [ 'Songs/A/a1.tsv', 'Songs/B/b1.tsv' ]
def zipFile = new File("deployment_zipFile.zip")
new AntBuilder().zip( basedir: HOME,
                      destFile: zipFile.absolutePath,
                      includes: deploymentFiles.join( ' ' ) )
```

Creates a zip file which when extracted contains:

```
unzip ../deployment_zipFile.zip 
Archive:  ../deployment_zipFile.zip
   creating: Songs/
   creating: Songs/A/
  inflating: Songs/A/a1.tsv          
   creating: Songs/B/
  inflating: Songs/B/b1.tsv
```