# Back up folder in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Using the `AntBuilder` seems to be the best way to create a backup zip file in Groovy. There are lots of solutions on this site that use methods like `copy` and `zip` but I can't see those methods the `AntBuilder` class in Groovy 2.1.5. Do I need to install an additional Jar?

```
new AntBuilder().zip(
    destfile: "mydir/myzip.zip") {
    fileset(dir: "mydir/myFile.txt")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods in `AntBuilder` are dynamic and depend on the installed ant tasks.

Did you try zipping a folder with it before asking here?

If you try, you should see it works

[Zip specific files with AntBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978846/zip-specific-files-with-antbuilder)

[Zip files/Directories in Groovy with AntBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225264/zip-files-directories-in-groovy-with-antbuilder)

Comment: I have tried it seeing exceptions, so it looks like a jar is missing: Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException

Comment: How are you ruining it and what are you running?

Comment: I'm using the Groovy Eclipse plugin. Right click on groovy file and Run As > Groovy Script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48128/discussion-between-user86834-and-tim-yates)